# How to debug a program that uses input from an auxiliary txt file in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb, stdin, fopen, c99

I want to debug a file, say file.c, and this file reads information from a txt file, say input.txt. So normally, to compile and run the program I would do the following:

```
gcc -std=c99 -g file.c -o file.exe
```

and to debug I would try the following:

```
gdb ./file.exe input.txt
```

However this doesn't work and fails with `No such file exits. '(null)': Bad address` when the program, file.c, attempts to open the file specified in argv[1] which input.txt is.

I have tried the following methods:

```
1. gdb ./file.exe
   (gdb) run < input.txt
```

```
2. gdb ./file.exe
   b main
   (gdb) r
   (gdb) call (int)dup2(open("input.txt",0),0)
   $1 = 0
```

All with the same outcome as described above...`No such file exits. '(null)': Bad address`

The code is merely:

```
FILE *input = fopen(argv[1],"r");
```

Comment: `(gdb) run input.txt`

Comment: Your file is expected as a parameter, not redirected stream.

Comment: Try `gdb --args ...`

Comment: regarding: `FILE *input = fopen(argv[1],"r");`  This will not compile.  It needs: 1) `#include <stdio.h>` 2) `int main( void ){ FILE *input = fopen(argv[1],"r"); ....` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do

```
gdb --args ./file.exe file.txt
b main
run
```

or do

```
gdb ./file.exe
b main
run file.txt
```